# Woocommerce 3.0 related products filtering

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to exclude products from related products section that have an attribute with a certain value. For example, I want related products by category except the ones with the attribute `attribute_value('pa_season') = summer;`

I tried this but it does not working

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', 'filter_related_products' );
function filter_related_products( $args ) {
    global $product;
    return array(
       'post_type'            => 'product',
       'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
       'no_found_rows'        => 1,
       'posts_per_page'       => 4,
       'orderby'              => 'ASC',
       'post__not_in'         => array( $product->get_id() ),
       'tax_query'      =>     array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'pa_epoxi',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => 'autumn-winter'
              )
        )
    );
}
```

EDIT: I found that I can use the filter 
[woocommerce_product_related_posts_query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0b60af0774d998ce949c7eb71257b2a91bc7c370/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L981) to edit the query that fetchs related products from the database.

I tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', function( $query ) {
    $query['where'] .= " AND t.term_id !=100";
    return $query;
});
```

But I get an error reporting: Unknown column 't.term_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to exclude the term ids I wanted by using the filter [woocommerce_product_related_posts_query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L1130) and editing the SQL query like this:

```
function exclude_terms_from_related_products( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $exclude_term_ids[0] = 100; // term_id
    $query['join']  .= " LEFT JOIN ( SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ( " . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $exclude_term_ids ) ) . ' ) ) AS exclude_join1 ON exclude_join1.object_id = p.ID';
    $query['where'] .= ' AND exclude_join1.object_id IS NULL';
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', 'exclude_terms_from_related_products' );
```